# How do you store away freshly peeled and sliced potatoes?

Tags: storage

After peeling potatoes and slicing them to your desired size, how do I store them away?

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with storing pre-cut potatoes is oxidation, where they start to turn brown from contact with the air.   To prevent this, store them submerged in water.  You can get about 24 hours, refrigerated, in this manner.

This is is how restaurants that do natural cut fries store the pre-cut fries.

Comment: This has the added benefit for fries of removing excess starch from the surface. The fries get crisper in the outside, fluffier on the inside. It's a bit of a disadvantage for baked applications (like gratins) but not much. It doesn't seem to make much difference for mashed.

Answer (score 0):

Would putting some lemon juice on the surface also work?

I know lemon juice is sometimes used on sliced apples... it works slightly differently by being oxidized itself rather than the apples.

Comment: For duplicate questions, please only add answers to the question they are duplicates of.